# Adding more than one path item to a JSONB field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in a table and I want to add data to it. The record exists but I don't know if the json structure exists.

```
UPDATE 
    car 
SET 
    features = jsonb_set(
        features, 
        '{exterior,colour}', 
        to_jsonb('red'::text)
    ) 
WHERE 
    id = '81782'
```

The PostgreSQL documentation states the following:

> Note: All the items of the path parameter of jsonb_set must be present
>   in the target, unless create_missing is true, in which case all but
>   the last item must be present.

But I really would like to create the whole path if it is not there. Of course I could first add the first level and then the next but I rather use only one query.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it it possible to use a case statement & the `?` Operator which checks for top-level key existence.

The `UPDATE` statement can be written AS

```
UPDATE car 
SET 
  features = 
    CASE
      WHEN features ? 'exterior' THEN
        JSONB_SET(features, '{exterior, color}', TO_JSONB('red'::TEXT))
      ELSE JSONB_SET(features, '{exterior}', '{"color": "red"}'::JSONB)
    END
WHERE id = '81782';
```